# Norm on vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I was given a true or false questionnaire to study for my final and do not know if I am right or wrong about these statements. I marked the following statement as True:

> If $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on a vector space $X$, then so is $\displaystyle p(x)=\frac{\|x\|}{1+\|x\|}$.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$p(\lambda x) \neq \vert \lambda \vert p(x)$ so $p$ is not a norm.

Answer (score 1):

You probably had in mind the same statement for distances (which holds true).